# Parse error when using example Python code for REST API "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream"

Tags: python, parse-platform, ironpython

I can't figure out what is going on. I am using example python code found [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-basic-queries) to do a basic query on a Parse class. I am using the following code:

```
import json,httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/MY-CLASS', '', {
   "X-Parse-Application-Id": "MY-APP-ID",
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "MY-REST-API-KEY"
 })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

I Get the Following Messages:

```
Runtime error (IOException): Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
Traceback:
line 280, in do_handshake, "C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5.0 (64-bit)\Plug-ins\IronPython\Lib\ssl.py"
line 120, in __init__, "C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5.0 (64-bit)\Plug-ins\IronPython\Lib\ssl.py"
line 336, in wrap_socket, "C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5.0 (64-bit)\Plug-ins\IronPython\Lib\ssl.py"
line 1156, in connect, "C:\Program Files\Rhinoceros 5.0 (64-bit)\Plug-ins\IronPython\Lib\httplib.py"
line 3, in script
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!
-Zach

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.
Maybe a Firewall is blocking your request? It seems to stop during the ssl handshake.